# How to save image in a subdirectory using file_put_contents and return the path in php

Tags: php, wamp, folder-permissions

I am new to PHP but have experience in .net. I need to know a way to save images uploaded to a PHP page in a subdirectory of that page and return its path. I have checked and not found a way to give permission to an existing subdirectory in PHP. I am using wamp for development.

1. passed subdirectory in file_put_contents with the image file name.
2. got full path and appended the subdirectory.

```
$ImagePath = __DIR__.'/driverimages/'.$ImageName ;
file_put_contents($ImagePath, base64_decode($data->profilepic));
```

I know that if I create a directory from a PHP script with 0774 permission I can write to it. But I need to write to an existing subdirectory and return the image path so that it can be used in the front end to show the image.

I need to be able to write to a subdirectory from the current directory and return the path of the written image file.

Comment: I don't want to argue over this. You have given your remark by downvoting and that's ok. Thanks but I will find my way.

Comment: Are you sure the the `driverimages` folder exists below the folder that contains this script? On windows folder access permissions are almost never the issue, unless you have done something very odd to your windows system

Comment: Add [error reporting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/845021/) to the
top of your file(s) _while testing_ right after your opening PHP tag for example
`<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` to see if it yields anything.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ImagePath = __DIR__.'/driverimages/'.$ImageName;

mkdir(dirname($ImagePath),777);

file_put_contents($ImagePath, base64_decode($data->profilepic));
```

Comment: Thanks, @dılo sürücü, but can't I get or enable permission to an existing folder?.

Comment: I have referred PHP documentation, but I couldn't find any good examples in this regard.